# What is the cardinality of the following set $\{(A,B,C) : A ⊂ B ⊂ C ⊂ \{1,2,...,n\}\}$

Tags: combinatorics

> Calculate the cardinality of the following set $$\{(A,B,C) :  A ⊂ B ⊂ C ⊂ \{1,2,...,n\}\}$$

Hi, I need help solving this.
I don't really know how to approach this exercise.
I think it has something to do with **Inclusion–exclusion principle** though I don't know to which cases should I split the question (if that's even the direction).

Any help would be very appreciated, even an idea on where to start :)

thanks!

Comment: By "power" do you mean the cardinality?

Comment: or the "power set of $\{ A,B,C\}"$?

Comment: Also: here, does $\subset$ mean $\subseteq$, or does it mean $\subsetneqq$ ?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio yes! I'll edit the post! sorry

Comment: and the meaning is to ⫋

Answer (score 1):

Choosing three subsets $A,B,C$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ is equivalent to choosing a $3\times n$ matrix filled with zeroes and ones; the first row has a $1$ in all columns corresponding to elements of $A$, and zeroes elsewhere, and similarly for the other rows with $B$ and $C$.

Imagine filling this matrix one column at a time. What does the condition $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$ imply each column look like? How many choices are there for each column?

**Added later**: I thought that condition was $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$, in which case there are four ways to choose each column, for $4^n$ ways to choose the matrix. I see now that the condition is $A\subsetneq B\subsetneq C$, which is just a little trickier. As you suspected, you need the principle of inclusion exclusion.

You just need to subtract the cases where $A=B$, and where $B=C$. Using the same strategy as before, the number of triples $(A,B,C)$ where $A=B\subseteq C$ is equal to $3^n$, because we are choosing a binary $2\times n$ matrix, and the condition $B\subseteq C$ only allows three possibilities for each column. The same goes for triples with $B=C$. However, triples where $A=B=C$ have been doubly subtracted, so those need to be added back in. The final result is
$$
4^n-3^n-3^n+2^n
$$

Comment: Hey! thank you so much!
I tried your first suggestion, before trying the trickier (and the actual) case. the equation I got is this:
$$ \sum_{k1+k2+k3=n}^{n-2 }{n-2 \choose k1}{n-1 \choose k2}{n \choose k1} $$ since I have n-2 options for elements in A, n-1 in B and n in C. I understand this is wrong, but I don't understand what I don't understand properly. ):

Comment: okay I went over your solution again, and I understand it better now, but I feel like I don't understand fully why we have $4^n$ options for A⊆B⊆C

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $$E_{j,k}=\{A\subset B \subset C \subset \{1,2,3 \cdots n\} \backslash \lvert A \rvert =j, \lvert B \rvert =k; 1\leq j< k < n\}$$
How many possibilities are there to choose $A$? , once you have chosen $A$, you have freedom only in choosing $B\setminus A$ .
What is the relation between the set you want to calculate its cardinality and the sets $E_{j,k}$ ?